# Cannot import name 'transformer' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use the transformer module in python.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-db3d3c91b7dc> in <module>
      3 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
      4 
----> 5 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Transformer
```

I have Tensorflow 2.11 recently installed (upgraded to) in order to make use of this

I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting this issue

I have tried upgrading my Tensorflow installation with pip - unfortunately the error persists

Comment: Can you print `tensorflow.keras.layers.__file__` and ensure that it is the location and version you expect? Often import errors are caused by multiple python installs/PATH issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no transformer layer available in [tf.keras.layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers) API. Hence caused the above error. Please try again by installing **Transformer** module first and then import it using below code:

```
!pip install transformers
import transformers
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and have installed transformers.  Can I use this as a Tensorflow layer?  Something like:

model = Sequential()
model.add(Transformer([parameters])